# Sonar "Dead store to local variable" violation when create DateTime and add seconds

Tags: datetime, sonarqube

I would like to create org.joda.time.DateTime with current time + 10 sec. Now I use this code:

```
DateTime testTime = new DateTime();    
testTime = testTime.plusSeconds(10);
```

But Sonar generates ***Dodgy - Dead store to local variable*** violation. I suppose that the problem is the instantiating of DateTime in first step because in the second step it is overwritten with a new instance (because `plusSeconds` method creates copy).

How to solve this? Is there some best practice - e.g. avoid the creation of two instances ("create current time and add same time in one step")?

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
DateTime testTime = new DateTime().plusSeconds(10);
```